# Vue component not initialized when inserted into the page after the page load

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, vue.js, widget

I am trying to insert a vue component into the page after the page is completely loaded.

The component works fine when the htlm is already on the page.

this is the blade containing the component:

```
<div id="widget{{ $item->getId() }}">

<input type="hidden" name="settings[{{ $item->getId() }}][keep]" value="1" />

<fieldset class="widget-pod">

    <legend class="title-legend visuallyhidden">Image</legend>

    <imageupload
        width="{{ $width }}"
        height="{{ $height }}"
        input-name="settings[{{$item->getId()}}][image]"
        path="{{ $item->downloadRoute('content_id') }}"
        alt="{{ $settings->get('image_alt') }}">
    </imageupload>

</fieldset>

</div>
```

And this is the javascript function that adds it into the page:

```
this.add = function(element, callback) {

var naturalHeight = $(element).height();

$(element)
  .css('height', 0)
  .css('max-height', '999999px')
  .css('min-height', 0)
  .animate({
      height: naturalHeight + 'px'
    },
    this.getDuration() * 1000,
    function() {
      removeHeightAndSetMarginAndPadding($(element));

      //if the natural height changes throughout the animation, some javascipt happened so let's just animate it again
      if ($(element).height() !== naturalHeight) {
        var newNaturalHeight = $(element).height();
        $(element)
          .css('height', naturalHeight)
          .animate({
              height: newNaturalHeight + 'px'
            },
            (self.getDuration() / 2 * 1000),
            function() {
              if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback();
              }
            }
          );

      } else {
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
          callback();
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

};

Comment: Where is your root Vue instance?

Comment: It's in my app.js inside resources/assets/js.

Comment: To be clear, the JS Code is _inside_ your VueJS component?

Comment: No the js code to add the element to the page is not in the component. It is included in the page before the components.